# Probability of at least one tail in 3 coin flips

Tags: probability

The question is:

What is the probability of getting at least 1 tail, when you flip a fair coin three times?

I know the answer is $\frac 7 8$. But initially I wrote it as $\frac{\binom{3}{1}\cdot2^2}{2^3}$

Because there are $\binom 3 1$ ways to choose one of them which has tails, and then $2^2$ ways to choose the remaining results for the other two flips. And the sample space is of course $2^3$.

Obviously my answer is wrong, it gets you $\frac 3 2$ as a probability. But I am struggling to figure out why my approach doesn't work.

Comment: Double counting.  You count the sequence TTH twice, once for each tails.  You count TTT $3$ times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach overcounts the possiblilites:

The first coin being T and the rest being H or T gives {THH, THT, TTH, TTT}. The second coin being T and the rest being H or T gives {HTH, HTT, TTH, TTT}. Notice that TTT and TTH appear in both. In fact you have counted TTT 3 times, and each of TTH, THT, and HTT two times, for a total of 5 overcounts. If you subtract (12-5)/8, you get the right answer again.